# Create freq for each row using DataFrame Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have this function:

```
for row in df:
    if (row[2]):
        media_list.append(df['Irradiance_PV1'].groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min')]).agg(["min", "max"]))       

df['Media']=pd.Series(media_list)
```

But this function indicate the maximum and minimum for an interval of 10 minutes, I want to calculate for a 10 minute interval, but for each line, as in this example:

```
DataTime    Irradiance      máx      min
00:01          500          800      500
00:02          512          830      512    
00:03          600          900      530          
00:04          670           .        . 
00:05          530           .        .
00:06          700           .        .
00:07          760
00:08          800
00:09          700
00:10          730
00:11          830
00:12          900
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ?

```
df['min']=df.ix[::-1, 'Irradiance'].rolling(10).min()[::-1]
df['max']=df.ix[::-1, 'Irradiance'].rolling(10).max()[::-1]
#take off NaN by adding `min_periods=1`
#df.ix[::-1, 'Irradiance'].rolling(10,min_periods=1).max()[::-1]

df
Out[49]: 
   DataTime  Irradiance    max    min
0      0:01         500  800.0  500.0
1      0:02         512  830.0  512.0
2      0:03         600  900.0  530.0
3      0:04         670    NaN    NaN
4      0:05         530    NaN    NaN
5      0:06         700    NaN    NaN
6      0:07         760    NaN    NaN
7      0:08         800    NaN    NaN
8      0:09         700    NaN    NaN
9      0:10         730    NaN    NaN
10     0:11         830    NaN    NaN
11     0:12         900    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Yes,this is perfect! Thank you very much!!